# Тире или двоеточие после обобщающего слова?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Вопрос с другого ресурса. Интересно мнение этого сообщества.

Тире или двоеточие поставить после НИКТО?

От присутствия больших долгов не выигрывает никто - ни заёмщик, ни кредитор.

Comment: Присутствие?.. Ну не уместное же слово для данного случая. Наличие, существование. И дело даже не в самой величине долгов для возникновения дискомфортных отношений, а в затягивании сроков возврата. Ну, это просто реплика.

Comment: А что за ресурс-то?

Comment: Понял. Ну так там и уровень соответствующий. Жалко, что Стэк на этот уровень скатывается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Людмила, а по-моему, здесь приложение, поэтому тире оправдано.

Если однородные члены предложения носят характер приложения или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться тире: 
 ***Легенды и сказки любят все — дети и взрослые;***

Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь.Д.Э.

Comment: Всем спасибо, мы оказались единодушны(в отличие от того ресурса, где признали лучшим ответом мнение об обязательности двоеточия ). В современной грамматике всё чаще двоеточие заменяется знаком тире, и это оправдано добавочными значениями приложений и уточнений.

Comment: Вы правы, Людмила. То же самое говорится как в справочнике Лопатина, так и Розенталя.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы поставил тире: двоеточие здесь можно было бы оправдать перечислением, но двух элементов для этого маловато, а суть высказывания состоит не в оглашении списка. Пояснять адресату две известных ему стороны ситуации, остановив его внимание двоеточием, тоже лишне. Здесь, скорее, имеет место риторическое подчёркивание очевидного: мол, сами понимаете, о ком речь - о том и этом.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта верны, предпочтение в выборе знака зависит от содержания текста.

1) Заемщику или кредитору выгодны большие долги? От присутствия больших долгов не выигрывает никто: **ни заёмщик, ни кредитор**. Здесь логически выделяется однородный ряд.

2) Кому-нибудь выгодны большие долги? От присутствия больших долгов не выигрывает **никто** - ни заёмщик, ни кредитор.  Здесь логически выделяется местоимение "никто", однородный ряд имеет присоединительное значение.